# Заполнение пустого пространства QPixmap картинкой

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap

У меня есть `painter`, который рисует размытую картинку с учетом поворота, масштабирования и движения.
То есть получается, допустим, следующее:

[image: это орел, картинка вверх ногами]

Вопрос: как рассчитать количество передвижений вверх/вниз/в стороны, чтобы заполнить этой картинкой все пространство, включая маленький уголок сверху слева?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас я попробовал сделать на коленке, понимаю что это грязно, но оно и не работает.

`main_rect` - основной кадр с черным фоном;
`transformed_rect` - квадрат, в котором рисуется картинка.

```
    QRect frame_to_rect(transformed_painter.transform().mapRect(QRect(0, 0, main_rect.width() * w_scale, main_rect.height() * h_scale)));
    if (frame_to_rect != main_rect) {

      int left_count(0), right_count(0), top_count(0), bottom_count(0);
      while (frame_to_rect.topLeft().x() - (frame_to_rect.width() * left_count) >= 0 || frame_to_rect.bottomLeft().x() - (frame_to_rect.width() * left_count) >= 0) { // сколько раз рисовать слева

        left_count++;
        transformed_painter.drawPixmap(-(main_rect.width() * left_count), 0, main_frame);
      }
      left_count += 1;
      while (frame_to_rect.topRight().x() + (frame_to_rect.width() * right_count) <= main_rect.width() || frame_to_rect.bottomRight().x() + (frame_to_rect.width() * right_count) <= main_rect.width()) { // справа

        right_count++;
        transformed_painter.drawPixmap((main_rect.width() * right_count), 0, main_frame);
      }
      right_count += 1;
      while (frame_to_rect.topLeft().y() - (frame_to_rect.height() * top_count) >= 0 || frame_to_rect.topRight().y() - (frame_to_rect.height() * top_count) >= 0) { // сверху

        top_count++;
        for (int i(left_count); i >= 0; i--)
          transformed_painter.drawPixmap(-(main_rect.width() * i), -((main_rect.height() * top_count)), main_frame);
        for (int i(1); i <= right_count; i++)
          transformed_painter.drawPixmap((main_rect.width() * i), -((main_rect.height() * top_count)), main_frame);
      }
      top_count += 1;
      while (frame_to_rect.bottomLeft().y() + (frame_to_rect.height() * bottom_count) <= main_rect.height() || frame_to_rect.bottomLeft().y() + (frame_to_rect.height() * bottom_count) <= main_rect.height()) {// снизу
        bottom_count++;

        for (int i(left_count); i >= 0; i--)
          transformed_painter.drawPixmap(-(main_rect.width() * i), ((main_rect.height() * bottom_count)), main_frame);
        for (int i(1); i <= right_count; i++)
          transformed_painter.drawPixmap((main_rect.width() * i), ((main_rect.height() * bottom_count)), main_frame);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

пока сделал следующим образом, работает, громоздко, но других вариантов не придумал

```
QRectF visible_rect(QPoint(0,0), additional_effect_.dev_rect_.size());
      QRectF transf_to_visible(transformed_painter.transform().map(QPoint(0, 0)),
                           transformed_painter.transform().map(QPoint(rect_width, rect_height)));

      if (transf_to_visible != main_frame.rect()) {

        int side_count(2);
        while (true) {

          bool all_outside(true);

          for (int count(-(side_count - 1)); count < side_count; count++) { // дорисовка сверху, снизу

            QPoint upper_top_left(rect_width * count, -rect_height * (side_count - 1)), lower_top_left(rect_width * count, rect_height * (side_count - 1));

            transf_to_visible = QRectF(transformed_painter.transform().mapRect(QRectF(upper_top_left, QSizeF(rect_width, rect_height))));
            if (visible_rect.intersects(transf_to_visible)) {

              transformed_painter.drawPixmap(rect_width * count, -rect_height * (side_count - 1), main_frame);
              all_outside = false;
            }
            transf_to_visible = QRectF(transformed_painter.transform().mapRect(QRectF(lower_top_left, QSizeF(rect_width, rect_height))));
            if (visible_rect.intersects(transf_to_visible)) {

              transformed_painter.drawPixmap(rect_width * count, rect_height * (side_count - 1), main_frame);
              all_outside = false;
            }
          }

          for (int count(-(side_count - 2)); count < side_count - 1; count++) { // дорисовка в стороны

            QPoint left_top_left(-rect_width * (side_count - 1), rect_height * count), right_top_left(rect_width * (side_count - 1), rect_height * count);
            transf_to_visible = QRectF(transformed_painter.transform().mapRect(QRectF(left_top_left, QSizeF(rect_width, rect_height))));
            if (visible_rect.intersects(transf_to_visible)) {

              transformed_painter.drawPixmap(-rect_width * (side_count - 1), rect_height * count, main_frame);
              all_outside = false;
            }
            transf_to_visible = QRectF(transformed_painter.transform().mapRect(QRectF(right_top_left, QSizeF(rect_width, rect_height))));
            if (visible_rect.intersects(transf_to_visible)) {

              transformed_painter.drawPixmap(rect_width * (side_count - 1), rect_height * count, main_frame);
              all_outside = false;
            }
          }

          if (all_outside) // если все расчитанные прямоугольники вышли за пределы области отрисовки - остановка
            break;

          side_count++; // количество 
        }
      }
```